# How to define a type for a function like this?

Tags: typescript

I'm moving some code to TS and I've been struggling to define a type for a group of routing functions. That's how they look like:

```
const root: Route = () => 'root'
root.child = () => `${root()}/child`
root.child.grandchild = () => `${root.child()}/grandchild`
```

I've tried to define some kind of recursive callable type or interface alongside an index signature for the nested attributes, but without much success:

```
type Route = {
  (): string
  [key: string]: Route
}
```

Any thoughts or ideas on how I can do that?

Playground: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gV2NAvFA3gKCjqAKASgC4oBnYAJwEsA7Ac21wG0BrCEE86+gXRPiQRMAX0yYAxnBrkoFOHGD9EyKGkKqAfFADkchdsx7gAOnEALKgBsAJqvwFNUAAYASdEcLCA9OavWnhvImvjbGdBQAhjTWIbZqDiharu5BphY2nl7hUTHp-mJAA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you are trying to do there are several options.

If you use a regular `function` definition you can just add extra properties to the function in the scope where the function was declared and TS will recognize these as properties on the function:

```
function root() { return 'root' }
function child() { return `${root()}/child` }
child.grandchild = () => `${root.child()}/grandchild`
root.child = child;



root.child.grandchild() //ok
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=8&ssc=24&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJznKAKAlIg3igUyhGSQHJV0zEBfAKFElgUQgAsYAbAE2z0OKlEAAwAkuSpiw0A9Oy7dhtOvJ4A6AObIAhmG6ruiALyI+RgHwjxktQeyytu-Rx7C6Ng8dYvuAbjoB7mhQtj6aOnp2WEA)

Another option is to use `Object.assign` to create the function with properties in one go:

```
const root = Object.assign(() => 'root', {
    child: Object.assign(() => `${root()}/child`, {
        grandchild: () => `${root.child()}/grandchild`
    })
});

root.child.grandchild()
```

[Play](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=8&ssc=24&pln=1&pc=1#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAJzGeBeOB5ARgKwKYgwB0AhlFAJYDmEAFLQJRyoB8cA5EiuwDRwDewOMLggAFhQA2AEwBcmXAWJlKNek1ZwABgBJ+XGIwC+AenFTpWvoJG24VBCQjTzM+Y2Ztd+5MVfTjEwcnFwkZLSERIwZgaIBuYGADIn8iYOd-RiA)

Neither of these options actually uses your `Router` interface which allows any string property to be later added. To do this, I think the simplest option is to create a helper function that will internally use `Object.assign` but that will also use the desired types:

```
type Route = {
    (): string
    [key: string]: Route
}

function createRoute(fn: () => string, other: Record<string, Route> = {}) {
    return Object.assign(fn, other);
}

const root: Route = createRoute(() => 'root', {
    child: createRoute(() => `${root()}/child`, {
        grandchild: createRoute(() => `${root.child()}/grandchild`)
    })
})
```

[Play](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=16&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gV2NAvFA3gKCjqAKASgC4oBnYAJwEsA7Ac21wG0BrCEE86+gXRPiQRMAX0yYAZghoBjYFTg0o0ihACGyASrziaJQlBQA+MpVp0ANFDjAAFhAr8I0uBQAmAHi5nLA5MbTowgQYjDgqwAgUigDyAEYAVk7AAHSqpKRUdDTaNJbWdhQEANwiYs405FAUcNb8iMgGSirqEJoQePpGUADk1dbdlli4SjZUADauJMpqGohancYABgAk6H3AhMIA9NKjE4uDocNQdBSqNK6745NNM61z7QtQK2s1KVcTm1un55d7rosCEcgiIgZggA)

Comment: Actually, those arrow functions are already written and there are a bunch of them, I'd rather keep it and just find a way to define a type for them. I will play around with your suggestion and see how it looks. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, is [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23226) one of the things stopping a more straightforward answer?  I guess callable types never get implicit index signatures for some reason.

Comment: @GuilhermeBaron there's always [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) so `const root = (() => 'root') as Route;` and `root.child = (() => \`${root()}/child\`) as Route;` etc.  It's strange that this would be necessary though...

Comment: @jcalz Yeah, assertions are always an option. I think in this case probably the simplest. Don't think any type safety is lost in this case.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23226) might be related. I'd like to be able to just do something like [that](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBATiEsC8MAUBKGyB8MDkCS+AUEVAHTAAWAlgDYAm26WuMABgCQDe5mAXwD0NBow5lElUUwoBzOAEMwjGc1SZsebnylU6TQUIXLVB8SSA) but looks like TS allows me to add just one level deep attribute to a function. Using the type assertion I don't get type safety, e.g. some of the subroutes arrow functions expect parameters and using assertions that are not validated by TS when calling those functions.